# Complexity of a Diophantine equation having $\leq1$ solutions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algorithms, computational-complexity

We are provided a single Diophantine equation
$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$$
having degree $\geq2$ and having the promise it has $\leq1$ solutions in the set $\{0,\dots,m-1\}^n$ and $t$ is the number of terms in the polynomial.

We are to decide if $$|\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\{0,1\}^n:f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0\}|>0?$$

Is there a $\mathsf{poly}(mnt)$ algorithm for the problem?

If $m=2$ degree of every $x_1$ to $x_n$ can be reduced to $1$.

I think for general $m$ it should be in $\mathsf{poly}(mnt)$.

---

Valiant-Vazirani is applicable but unless $t=\mathsf{poly}(n)$ a $\mathsf{poly}(nt)$ algorithm cannot resolve $\mathsf{NP}$ versus $\mathsf{BPP}$. It is not clear $\mathsf{SAT}$ is Valiant-Vazirani reducible to a $\mathsf{PromiseDiophantine}$ problem of having $\leq1$ integral solutions.

Comment: It is not clear if $SAT$ reduces to $t=poly(n)$ situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you could solve this problem in polynomial time, then NP would be contained in BPP, which is viewed as being approximately as unlikely as P = NP. Too see this, pick your favorite encoding of SAT into diophantine equations on $\{0,1\}^n$ (for instance, you can take $f$ to be a sum of squares of expressions corresponding to individual clauses), and apply the main result of *Valiant, L. G.; Vazirani, V. V.*, [**NP is as easy as detecting unique solutions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(86)90135-0), Theor. Comput. Sci. 47, 85-95 (1986). [ZBL0621.68030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0621.68030).

Comment: Notice $t$ could be very large compared to $n$ and number of terms is part of input and it is not clear if $t$ is say quasipolynomial in $n$.

Comment: @1.. The sum of squares of expressions for clauses approach makes $t$ proportional to the number of clauses (after reducing to 3SAT, say), which is counted in the size of the SAT instance, so it indeed gives a polynomial algorithm

Comment: @WillSawin I am not familiar on Sum of Squares expressions for clauses. Perhaps expand by little details in explanation?

Comment: @1.. For 3SAT, for the clause $(x_i \vee  x_j \vee x_k)$, take $ (1 - (1-x_i)(1-x_j)(1-x_k))^2$ and then sum the corresponding expression over all the clauses.